# Error on MathWorld: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\zeta(4n)-1) = \frac{1}{8}(7-2\coth \pi)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

I think that this identity is wrong:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\zeta(4n)-1) = \frac{1}{8}(7-2\coth \pi)$$

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html
(Identity 121 on this site)

It should be
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\zeta(4n)-1) = \frac{1}{8}(7-2\pi\coth \pi)$$

Do you agree or am I mistaken?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{i=1}^\infty(\zeta(4i)-1)$?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it would diverge

Comment: I think you are correct from my own numerical check.

Comment: Your title is misleading. The sum in Wolfram Alpha is correct http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum+_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty+%7D+(%5Czeta+(4+i)-1) You mean error in Wolfram MathWorld document

Comment: There are a lot of errors in mathworld.wolfram.com

Comment: I changed the title and the tags as it's in no way related to WolframAlpha. I also changed a bit the form of the correct answer to emphasize the typo (missing factor $\pi$).

Answer (score 1):

I agree there is a missing $\pi$. By the integral representation for the $\zeta$ function

$$\zeta(n)-1 = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\cdot\frac{dx}{e^x(e^x-1)} \tag{1}$$
holds for any $n>1$. In particular
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\zeta(4k)-1\right) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{e^x(e^x-1)}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^{4k+3}}{(4k+3)!}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sinh(x)-\sin(x)}{2e^x(e^x-1)}\,dx\tag{2} $$
where $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sinh(x)}{2e^x(e^x-1)}\,dx=\frac{3}{8}$ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{2e^x}\,dx=\frac{1}{4}$ are trivial and 
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{e^x-1}\,dx=\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{m^2+1}\tag{3} $$
due to the Laplace transform. The last series is well-known to be equal to $\frac{\pi\coth \pi-1}{2}$, for instance through the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula). Rearranging proves the claim (the second one).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the exact result is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\left(\zeta\left(4i\right)-1\right)=\frac{1}{8}\left(7-2\pi\text{coth}\left(\pi\right)\right)
$$

Check it [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(%20zeta(4n)-1)%20from%20n%3D1%20to%20n%3Dinfty)